# openlayers - wms - map not loading

Tags: javascript, geospatial, openlayers, wms

I've created a simple site with a map where I'm connecting to a wms-server.
The problem is now, that the map isn't shown, just a view small pictures. Here is the site i've created:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2418858/index.html

Here is the code i've been using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var wms;
        var map_controls = [new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                             new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(), 
                             new OpenLayers.Control.MouseToolbar(), 
                             new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()];

        function init() {
            map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
                controls : map_controls
            });
            wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Satellitenbild_30m", "http://gis.lebensministerium.at/wmsgw/", {
                layers : 'Satellitenbild_30m',
                key : '6ae2a41178c77ccee1db7248c9f92b04',
            }, {
                projection : new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:32632'),
                singleTile : true,
                buffer : 0,
                ratio : 1
            });

            map.addLayer(wms);

            map.zoomToMaxExtent();

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload=init()>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I'm using Spatial commander (a GIS-desktop-program) I'm seeing the map and can zoom-in and out, but when I'm using Openlayers I don't see a map.

So what I've done is intercepting the request vom Spatial Commander with a proxy to see how this request differs from mine sent from my website.

The only difference I've found was the BBOX parameter which in SC looked like this:

```
BBOX=495149.712089618,4954209.6147000715,1173065.9355847104,5633477.615310807
```

and the parameter in a request sent from my webpage looked like this:

```
BBOX=-351.5625,-351.5625,351.5625,351.5625
```

So I changed the BBOX parameter sent through my webpage manually and get this:
[manual request](http://gis.lebensministerium.at/wmsgw/?LAYERS=Satellitenbild_30m&KEY=6ae2a41178c77ccee1db7248c9f92b04&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&SRS=EPSG:32632&BBOX=495149.712089618,4954209.6147000715,1173065.9355847104,5633477.615310807&WIDTH=1000&HEIGHT=1000) So there was the map!

Now my actual questions:

- Why is'nt the map showing on my website?
- Why is the BBOX-parameter sent automatically from Openlayers so far off the values sent from spatial commander?
- How can I make my map work?

Thanks!

Comment: The only reason it's not working, is because the BBOX isn't being request in the projection you're using. I'm not actually sure how to fix it. May have something to do with declaring a maxExtent in the map initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint, because now I'm at least able to view a map, although the zoom-level is way off and I can't figure out the right maxExtent... [link]http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2418858/index1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the *property* `maxResolution` on the `map` object:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
    controls : map_controls,
    maxResolution: 1000
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this did the trick! Map is showing now like it's proposed to. I now just need to figure out how convert gps-coordinates... Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers only handles a couple of projections (Web Mercator and WGS84) itself. For other projections you need to include the Proj4js library available at - http://proj4js.org/

OpenLayers integrates automatically with this library if it is available (i.e. added to your web page).

Next add in the projection parameters for your projection (before it is used in your code). In this case EPSG:32632

You can get nearly all projection details from http://spatialreference.org (when the site is up) in the Proj4js format:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:32632"] = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
```

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32632/proj4js/

However looking at the capabilities of [your WMS service](http://gis.lebensministerium.at/wmsgw/?LAYERS=DOP,Orthophoto,Luftbild_MR,Satellitenbild_30m,Luftbild_8m,Luftbild_1m&KEY=6ae2a41178c77ccee1db7248c9f92b04&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) - it can be requested in Web Mercator projection as well - so there is no need for reprojections:

Finally, the demo link you sent is displaying a map - in FireFox at least.  Are you sure you don't have JavaScript errors? You have an extra comma in this line:

```
key : '6ae2a41178c77ccee1db7248c9f92b04',
```

This often causes Internet Explorer to stop showing the map.

Comment: thanks very much! I've now included Proj4js and also made the definition for epsg:32632 but now I've seen that my site sends a request for EPSG31287.js, which I don't know the definition for, since spatialreference.org is down...Will take a look when they're up again...

Comment: So I have included Proj4j in my site, but sadly it didn't change anything at all. same problem: map is showing but in a way too high zoom factor and i cannot change it, because then the map is not showing anymore...

Comment: firebug didn't show any script-errors, but I've fixed the comma. The problem is, when I change the projection to anything else, the map won't show...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't set projection on OpenLayers map object. In this case OpenLayers sets default projection which is "EPSG:4326". Then you can also set maxExtent property so that OpenLayers knows for which area it should send image requests. In init method do this:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
  controls : map_controls,
  projection: "EPSG:32632",
  maxExtent: new OepnLayers.Bounds(495149.712089618,4954209.6147000715,1173065.9355847104,5633477.615310807)                 
});
```

Comment: thanks! the problem in my case was that maxResolution was not set.